# session register doesnt work

Tags: php, session

I'm having a problem with registering sessions on my websites login script:
so the thing is like this, I'm working on my site with webmatrix and I worked on the same files on two different computers, also I have the site uploaded to a server. in all three cases it works just fine!
recently I created the very same working environment on a laptop I have, webmatrix + xampp mysql db - only here I found out that sessions refuse to be created, the code:

(the login page is included in the index.php page.

```
<?php
session_start();
$no_mail_pass_error="";
$no_user_error="";
$wrong_pass_error="";

if ($_POST['submit_login']){

$log_email = $_POST ["log_email"]; //VAR $email = to what usename has entered
$log_password = $_POST ["log_password"]; //VAR $password = to what usename has entered
$remember_me = $_POST ["remember_me"];

$log_email = strip_tags($log_email);
$log_password = strip_tags($log_password);

$log_email = mysql_real_escape_string($log_email);
$log_password = mysql_real_escape_string($log_password);

if ($log_email==""||$log_password=="") {
$no_mail_pass_error='
    <div id="login_errors_div" style="display:none;">
    <table border="0">
    <tr>
    <td>
    <img src="ec_mark_25.png"/>   
    </td>
    <td>
    no mail    
    </td>    
    </tr>
    </table>
    <hr />
     </div>

     ';
}
else {

$login_connect = mysql_connect ("***", "***", "***")

or die ("couldnt connect");
mysql_select_db (***) or die ("not found"); //if db was not found die
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

$login_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$log_email'"); //search for specific username entered

$login_numrows = mysql_num_rows($login_query); //check that it appears AT LEAST in ONE row

if ($login_numrows!=0) // IF IT APPEARS IN NONE - NO USER EXISTS

    {

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($login_query)) //Takes the whole row of the specific user and extracts all the fields
    {
        $dbemail = $row['email'];
        $dbpassword = $row['password']; //Sets thoes fields into variables
        $id = $row['id'];
        $log_firstname = $row['firstname'];
        $log_lastname = $row['lastname'];
    }

    if ($log_email==$dbemail&&md5($log_password)==$dbpassword)

    {

    if ($remember_me=='on') {
    setcookie ("email",$email,time()+604800);

          session_register('email');
          $_SESSION['email']=$log_email;

          session_register('id');
          $_SESSION['id']=$id;

          session_register('firstname');
          $_SESSION['firstname']=$log_firstname;

          session_register('lastname');
          $_SESSION['lastname']=$log_lastname;

    header ("Location: homepage.php");
    }
    else if ($remember_me=='') {

          session_register('email');
          $_SESSION['email']=$log_email;


          session_register('id');
          $_SESSION['id']=$id;

          session_register('firstname');
          $_SESSION['firstname']=$log_firstname;

          session_register('lastname');
          $_SESSION['lastname']=$log_lastname;


          header ("Location: homepage.php");
          }

    }
    else {
    $wrong_pass_error='
    <div id="wrong_pass_error_div" style="display:none;">
    <table border="0">
    <tr>
    <td>
    <img src="ec_mark_25.png"/>   
    </td>
    <td>
   wrong pass   
    </td>    
    </tr>
    </table>
    <hr />
     </div>
     ';
    }


    }

    else {
    $no_user_error='
    <div id="no_user_error_div" style="display:none;">
    <table border="0">
    <tr>
    <td>
    <img src="ec_mark_25.png"/>   
    </td>
    <td>
    user not found
    </td>    
    </tr>
    </table>
    <hr />
     </div>
     ';
    }
}

}
?>
<form name="login_form" id="logn_form" method="post" action="index.php">
<table border="0" style="margin-left: 60px; margin-bottom: 3px;">

    <tr>    

    <td id="login_info">mail</td>
    <td id="login_info">pass</td>
    <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td><input id="login_input" name="log_email" type="text"/></td>
    <td><input id="login_input" name="log_password" type="password"/></td>
    <td><input id="login_submit" name="submit_login" type="submit" value="enter"/></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td valign="top">
    <!-- TABLE FOR REMEMBER ME -->  
    <table style="margin: 0px; padding:0px;"><tr>
    <td>  
    <input name="remember_me" type="checkbox"/>
    </td>
    <td>remember me</td>
    </tr></table>
    <!-- TABLE FOR REMEMBER ME - END -->    
        </td>
    <td valign="top"><div style="margin-top: 5px; margin-right: 5px;"><a id="forgot_password_a" href="#">forgot pass</a></div></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
```

What could be preventing the sessions from registering?

Comment: Check your PHP version (I believe they differ from both environments). `session_register` has been deprecated as of PHP 5.3, and in PHP >= 5.4 removed. Just remove `session_register` and use `$_SESSION['key'] = "value";` instead. See [session_register](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-register.php) docs

Comment: this was it thanks a lot!! if you post it as an answer i can mark it..thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Posting my comment as an answer ;)

Check your PHP version (I believe they differ from both environments).

`session_register` has been deprecated as of PHP 5.3 and in PHP >= 5.4 removed. Just remove `session_register` and use `$_SESSION['key'] = "value";` instead.

See [session_register](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-register.php) docs.

Answer (score 0):

Check where PHP is saving your session data. You can find this with phpinfo() and you can change it inside php.ini. It's called session.save_path I think, and make sure that the apache user (or whatever web server) has write access to that directory.

Also look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-save-path.php